# Uncaught TypeError: _materialUi.Styles.ThemeManager is not a function

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui

I have written the following code

```
import React from 'react';
import mui from 'material-ui';
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
let ThemeManager = new mui.Styles.ThemeManager();
let Colors = mui.Styles.Colors;

injectTapEventPlugin();

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            messages : [{id: 1, text: 'Hi'}, {id: 2, text: 'Hello'}, {id: 3, text: 'World'}, {id: 4, text: 'test'}]
        };
    }

    getChildContext() {
        return {
            stores: this.props.stores,
            muiTheme: ThemeManager.getCurrentTheme()
        };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        ThemeManager.setPalette({
            primary1Color: Colors.blue500
        });     
    }

    render() {
        var messageNodes = this.state.messages.map((message) => {
            return (<div key={message.id}>{message.text}</div>);
        });
        return (<div>{messageNodes}</div>);
    }
}

App.childContextTypes = {
    stores: React.PropTypes.object,
    muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object
};

export default App;
```

But it keeps throwing error

```
Uncaught TypeError: _materialUi2.default.Styles.ThemeManager is not a function
```

I have searched and searched the internet and many people solved it

https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/1439

but the same solutions do not work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after posting your repo, I noticed that you are using mui 0.14, and after quick research it seems you no longer need a constructor for ThemeManager - which in prior versions you did.

just define it on import:

```
import ThemeManager from 'material-ui/lib/styles/theme-manager';
```

From: [Material-UI](http://www.material-ui.com/#/customization/themes)

Look at the example titled: *1. Using React Lifecycle Methods with Context*

Answer (score 0):

***Note*** The original question, to which I answered with this answer, contained:

```
const ThemeManager = new mui.Styles.ThemeManager();
```

---

It is your use of `const` as opposed to `let`. You want to intialize function classes using let.

**Const:**

> The const declaration creates a read-only reference to a value.

From: [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)

**Let:**

> The let statement declares a block scope local variable, optionally
>   initializing it to a value.

From: [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)

Depending on your transpiler you should be getting an error that ThemeManager is read-only

Comment: I changed const to let but still same problem. My code is available at github `https://github.com/abhitechdojo/MovieLensReact.git`

Comment: For whoever down-voted this, I would like an explanation.

Comment: It might be because you posted two answers ;). I up voted your first answer since it was correct. If you think what you posted is relevant, add it to the above post and delete this one to keep things clean.